# How to setup HTTP/S proxy to access Internet

Tags: proxy

I have have two Ubuntu machines:

- A with access to B, but without access to Internet
- B with with access to Internet

I provide access to Internet on machine A I would like to setup HTTP/HTTPS proxy on machine B and configure curl and apt-get to use this proxy.

On B I have set up nginx from docker image as follows:

```
docker run -d \
  --name nginx-auto-ssl \
  --restart on-failure \
  -p 80:80 \
  -p 443:443 \
  -e ALLOWED_DOMAINS=* \
  -e FORCE_HTTPS=false \
  valian/docker-nginx-auto-ssl
```

On A I set proxies

```
 export http_proxy=http://machine.b.com:80/
 export https_proxy=https://machine.b.com:443/
```

However, when I request Internet resource from A, I get information proxy is not configured:

```
curl http://www.facebook.com/ -v
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 172.25.10.202...
* Connected to machine.b.com (172.x.x.x) port 80 (#0)
> GET http://www.facebook.com/ HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: www.facebook.com
> Accept: */*
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
* Server openresty/1.13.6.1 is not blacklisted
< Server: openresty/1.13.6.1
< Date: Tue, 29 May 2018 12:52:38 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 562
< Last-Modified: Fri, 20 Apr 2018 14:42:38 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< ETag: "5ad9fc5e-232"
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
<
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to OpenResty!</title>
<style>
    body {
        width: 35em;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to OpenResty!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the OpenResty web platform is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

<p>For online documentation and support please refer to
<a href="https://openresty.org/">openresty.org</a>.<br/></p>

<p><em>Thank you for flying OpenResty.</em></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does 'B' have two network interfaces (one for internet, other one for 'A') ?

Comment: nginx is a web server, not a proxy. It looks like you're trying to run the OpenResty web platform as if it was a proxy server. If you want a proxy, you need squid (or some other proxy server).

Comment: @cmak.fr How can I check that?

Comment: @dobey From the official doc: "nginx [engine x] is an HTTP and reverse proxy server". I just used docker image of nginx with OpenResty installed. I might try squid, though. Thanks.

Comment: @dzieciou a "reverse proxy" is something else. It's for proxying requests made to an externally facing web server, to other internal servers which aren't exposed to the network directly. It's not what you want, but rather Squid is.

Comment: Too broad. You can do this with ssh , squid, privoxy, or a number of proxy.  https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+http+proxy+ovee+ssh is but one of many options

Comment: @dobey I just did it with nginx and it works fine. Thanks for listening.

Comment: Does it have to be a HTTP proxy? Why not simply make B work as a network router? Or if they're not on the same network you can use some more generic proxy protocol like SOCKS via SSH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike some claimed, it is possible to do it with nginx proxy.

Here's `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx_proxy:
    container_name: "proxy"
    image: reiz/nginx_proxy:latest
    ports:
      - 8888:8888
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:ro
```

Here's `nginx.conf`:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
daemon off; # Don't run Nginx as daemon, as we run it in Docker we need a foreground process.
events {}

http {
  server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;

  access_log /var/log/nginx_access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx_errors.log;

  # Whitelist Google and Heise
  server {
    listen 8888;
    proxy_connect;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
    resolver 8.8.8.8;
    location / {
      proxy_pass http://$http_host;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }
  }

}
```